# How to vertically align social media buttons

Tags: html, css, facebook, button, twitter

I'm trying to vertically align a generated Facebook 'Share' button and a Twitter 'tweet' button but I can't seem to do it. I have included a code snippet but for some reason the Facebook button won't generate. You can view the problem on my website [here](https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/property-191/residential/for-sale/alexandra-drive-aigburth-l17).

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

```html
<div class="socialMediaButtons" style="vertical-align:top;">
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/property-191/residential/for-sale/alexandra-drive-aigburth-l17" data-layout="button"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"{count} data-url="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/property-191/residential/for-sale/alexandra-drive-aigburth-l17" data-related="atlasestates" data-hashtags="property">Tweet</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the alignment the problem or the fact that the Facebook button is not shown? There is a difference between title & content ... I suppose that alignment works fine.

Comment: Just the alignment, the Facebook button shows on my website. If you view my website, you'll see what I mean, the 'Tweet' button is higher than the 'Share' button (or vice versa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible by using `vertical-align:middle` in addition to move the Facebook button a bit using `top` property.

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: -2px;
}

#twitter-widget-0 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```